# Google Analytics 4 API - pagePathPlusQueryString

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I would like to pull the data for pagePathPlusQueryString , sessionCampaignName & totalUsers using google analytics 4 API ( POST  https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runReport).

It is giving me the incompatibility error when I add sessionCampaignName to the dimensions.

Dimensions: date, pagePathPlusQueryString & sessionCampaignName

```
"dimensions": [
 {
  "name": "date"
},
 {
  "name": "pagePathPlusQueryString"
},
{
  "name": "sessionCampaignName"
}
 ]
```

Metrics: totalUsers & screenPageViews

```
"metrics": [
{
  "name": "totalUsers"
},
{
  "name": "screenPageViews"
}
```

]

Is there any way that we can get the data with querystring & sessionCampaignName ?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.. Thanks.

Incompatibility issues with pagePathPlusQueryString & sessionCampaignName

Answer (score 1):

We running into same issue a few days ago.

Found these information from GA4 document

---

**Dimensions that include the query string like pagePathPlusQueryString will only be compatible with a limited set of dimensions & metrics.**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/announcements/20221201-compatibility-changes#metrics_compatible_with_query_string_dimensions

---

So we get the queryString into event parameter then it should work.

Seems like the `pagePathPlusQueryString` is still like page level dimension and different from regular event parameter.

---

### About How to get the custom event parameter from GA4 Data API

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#custom_dimensions

When you have custom event parameter, dimensions or metrics. You can just replace the dimensions and metrics like

`customEvent:{parameter_name}`

Then it should work like standard parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please can you send me the code/JSON, if possible.. Thanks

Comment: Hi, not sure what you want about the code or json? Like how to setup a custom event?

Comment: Hi, Yes, it will be great if you share the details how you setup a custom event and how are you pulling the campaign data with pagePath and QueryString. Thanks

Comment: For setup a custom event. It will need to ask who is doing the GTM and GA4 implementation. If that is someone else, we need to ask them to track this as a custom event. Once the tracking is done. The `GA4 Data API` can pull the data out. The difference is only the dimension. I will add up in the answer.

Comment: We added it on GTM and it's working on API("customEvent:name") but we are not getting full length of string.. needs to check. Thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail on the full length of string. Seems like an odd situation. Is your parameter value like really that long?

Comment: Looks like, GA4 has limitation on event parameter. Length of event-parameter value : 100 characters